# How to access rest API that is on eureka server by angular

Tags: angular, rest, netflix-eureka

How to access rest API that is on eureka server by angular client.

This is how I am doing right now. It is working but I want to access api without port number.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/product/'+localStorage.getItem('Id'))
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.response = response;
      console.log(this.response);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This port number is here because you are developping on local, in production you will configure a routing roule and the user will not see it.

If you realy whant to remove the port number from your dev machine try using **angular proxy**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable cors since angular is blocking it for that you have to add this piece of code to your class annotated with @EnableZuulProxy should do the trick.

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: i have added @CrossOrigin annotation in my api to enable CORS. i want to know how to acesss api that is on eureka server without port number . with port number it is working fine.